# How to waken myself when sleepy without causing much distraction to other employees?

Tags: office

[This question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/how-do-you-stay-productive-during-the-afternoon-energy-slump/6292#6292) specifically ask about the afternoon energy slump, I am curious on what things can I do in order to waken myself up without causing much distraction to other employees in my office? There are times that I really feel sleepy specially during working hours even though I have enough sleep.

Right now I'm limited on taking coffee and standing while programming are there anything else that I can do to waken myself?

Comment: Both the question you linked to, which is already voted off-topic, and this belongs rather on Personal Productivity SE than here on Lifehacks SE. Here they are related to mindhacks which are off-topic.

Comment: Answers are not necessarily mental-only, and the family of possible solutions suggested by the question (coffee, standing) are physical.

Comment: Yes, this speaks about physical hacks which can be done by standing, drinking coffee. Am sure that there are still more.

Comment: Headphones and energizing music.

Comment: Yes the solution to this problem can be physical. This question should not be closed

Comment: It's closed, but I'll answer: go for a run. I know that's extreme, but it'll pep you up. But you could also go up and down some flights of stairs and/or go for a brisk walk. Finally, another option is to drink cold water and avoid food - hunger keeps you awake, food makes you sleepy.

Comment: Mind hacks need not to be mental to be off topics, and it is not good enough for the answers to be physical. See specification of reasoning: "... _dealing with personal productivity_ ... "

Answer (score 2):

Wet your (clean) fingers and rub/splash some water in your eyes.  It doesn't last very long but it might help waken you up for a few minutes.

Longer term, consider what you're eating for breakfast, lunch, and other snacks, and what exercise you're getting.